# aggregate pipeline string forming

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
if (field) {
    if (field === "3") {
        // count_query_match = { $match:{ $and:[ {partyName:{'$regex' : '^'+search+'$', '$options' : 'i'}} ,{company_id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id)} ]} }
        count_query_match = { $match: { partyName: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' }, company_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id) } }
    } else if (field === "4") {
        count_query_match = { $match: { pr_phoneNumber: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } } }
    } else if (field === "5") {
        count_query_match = { $match: { vehicleNo: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } } }
    }
}

//   count_query_match = {
//     ...count_query_match,company_id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id)
// }

console.log(count_query_match);

count_query_group = {
    $group: {
        // _id : "$partyName",
        _id: null,
        netWeight: { $sum: "$netWeight" },
        netweightXvalue: { $sum: "$netweightXvalue" },
        netValue: { $sum: "$netValue" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}

data5 = await Productregistration.aggregate([count_query_match, count_query_group]);

res.status(200)
    .json({
        success: true,
        count: data5.length,
        // data1: data5[0],
        data2: data5
    });
```

how can i add company_id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id) condition to all aggregate count query match function in common like and condition.

in normal query i will do like this do add common condtions

```
query = {
    ...query,
    company_id: req.user.company_id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these 2 approaches:

**Directly add the common condition as a property to the** `$match`

```
 if (field) {
    if (field === "3") {
        count_query_match = { $match: { partyName: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } }}
    } else if (field === "4") {
        count_query_match = { $match: { pr_phoneNumber: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } } }
    } else if (field === "5") {
        count_query_match = { $match: { vehicleNo: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } } }
    }
}

count_query_match["$match"].company_id =  company_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id);
```

**Using another variable `match` for forming the dynamic query and then spreading it with the common condition**

```
let match;
if (field) {
    if (field === "3") {
        match = { partyName: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' }};
    } else if (field === "4") {
        match = { pr_phoneNumber: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } };
    } else if (field === "5") {
        match = { vehicleNo: { '$regex': '^' + search + '$', '$options': 'i' } };
    }
}

const count_query_match = {
      $match: {
        ...match,
        company_id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.company_id)
      }
};
```